# Try fix professor cloud carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have a question about jQuery cloud carousel (http://professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm).
Now we can put in container only images with class "carousel". But if I need put in container div with class carousel, this plugin doesn't work. I try change code, but I see same situation.
And I would like add class tu current element.
Can anybody help me?

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#wrap").CloudCarousel({  
            xPos: 398,
            yPos: 25,
            buttonLeft: $("#left-but"),
            buttonRight: $("#right-but"),
            altBox: $("#alt-text"),
            titleBox: $("#title-text"),
            FPS: 50,
            //autoRotate: 'left',
            autoRotateDelay: 1200,
            speed: 0.2,
            bringToFront: true,
            mouseWheel: false,
            minScale: 0.4,
            reflHeight: 86,
            reflGap: 10
        });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap" style="width:796px; height:338px; background:#000; overflow:scroll;">
        <div class = "cloudcarousel"><img src="img/1.gif" alt="Image One" /></div>
        <div class = "cloudcarousel"><img src="img/2.gif" alt="Image Two" /></div>
        <div class = "cloudcarousel"><img src="img/3.gif" alt="Image Three" /></div>
        </div>
</body>
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have loaded the jQuery and cloud carousel javascript correctly, and have initialized everything fine, I believe the `class="cloudcarousel"` needs to be part of the `img` element and not the `div`.

I don't see the purpose of the `div` tags around your images.